# gridsearchCV error while using one hot encoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

i am getting this error while using gridsearch cv with one hot encoding:
"Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets"

My y_train shape is:(64345, 37) and my X_train shape is:(64345, 14).

I'm not able to figure out where did i went wrong.Any guidance/help would be greatly appreciated.

It executes properly for my model without using gridsearchCV with fixed parameters.
Without using one hot encoding i am getting index out of bound error.
link for that post is here: [I was training an Ann machine learning model using GridSearchCV and got stuck with an IndexError in gridSearchCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131814/i-was-training-an-ann-machine-learning-model-using-gridsearchcv-and-got-stuck-wi)

here is how i split the dataset:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
df = onehotencoder.fit_transform(df).toarray()
df=df[:,1:]

target=df[:,0:37]
dataset=df[:,37:51]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(dataset,target,random_state=1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train= sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=pd.DataFrame(X_test)
```

here is gridseachcv code:

```py
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
def build_classifier(optimizer, nb_layers,unit):
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = unit, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 14))
    i = 1
    while i <= nb_layers:
        classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu", units=unit, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
        i += 1
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 37, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'softmax'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier)
parameters = {'batch_size': [10,25,32,64,128,256],
              'epochs': [50,100, 200,500,1000,1500,2000],
              'optimizer': ['adam'],
              'nb_layers': [2,3,4,5,6],
              'unit':[28,40,48,57]
             }
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                          cv=10,n_jobs=-1)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
```

i should be getting the best parameters in result but im getting error-
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message is clear.

Here, you have `y_train:(64345, 37)` which means that each sample is multi-labeled. You have 37 labels for each sample.

The classification metrics of sklearn cannot handle multi-labeled target variables.

You should look for a way to get `y_train:(64345, 1)` before applying the `GridSearch()`

---

For models that can deal with multilabel problems red this:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

```
Support multilabel:

sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier
sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV
```

Comment: i tried searching for that but till no i have not been able to fix this issue, if you have any document or any helping material it would be great help. Appreciate your help...

Comment: see my updated answer and consider accepting my answer

Comment: I have converted my y_train to (64345,) but i am getting another error pllease look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131814/i-was-training-an-ann-machine-learning-model-using-gridsearchcv-and-got-stuck-wi/58137004#58137004